# Facebook graph API, Live video no username

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I'am trying to understand the way Facebook graph API works.

Here is what I get with the following line live_id?fields=comments{from{name,id}, message}:

```
{
  "comments": {
    "data": [
      {
        "message": "Bonjour",
        "id": "628608838599395_1347565795803891"
      }]
}}
```

Any ideas?

I have setup all the possible permissions for Facebook business Login, Messenger and Instragram Graph API.

I have generated a page access token and I set my application to live. I'am able to retrieve comments but I cannot retrieve the username of the person that published the comment.